# How to Get VBA Codes to Repeat Inputs

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for some help with a project I am working on. I am trying to program a VBA code to ask the user for their name and in the following text box have it say hello, followed by their name.  I have looked for any help but cannot seem to find any. Any help would be appreciated.

This is what I currently have, I am trying to get it to say hello in the 4th line of code, following the "hello".

```
Sub GetValue()

    Dim name As String
    name = Application.InputBox("Please enter your name")
    
    MsgBox "Hello, (inputbox1.text)"
    MsgBox "Use the grade calculator to find the total marks you need to score in the final exam in order to meet your expectations, given every mark other than the final exam mark"
    MsgBox "Best of luck"
    MsgBox "Please enter all your current marks and the overall mark that you desire (/100)- Start entering from cell G9"

    Debug.Print name
End Sub
```

Comment: Just use `MsgBox "Hello " & name & ","` instead of `MsgBox "Hello, (inputbox1.text)"`.  I think that's what you want. Also have a look [here](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-inputbox/) and [here](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-msgbox/).

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're trying. I use `vbCr` to force a new line in the msgbox.

```
Sub GetValue()

    Dim name As String
    name = Application.InputBox("Please enter your name")
    
    MsgBox "Hello " & name & "," & vbCr & _
        "Use the grade calculator to find the total marks you need to score in the final exam in order to meet your expectations, given every mark other than the final exam mark" & vbCr & _
        "Please enter all your current marks and the overall mark that you desire (/100)" & vbCr & _
        "Start entering from cell G9" & vbCr & _
        "Best of luck!"

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello there, I tried that and it didn't seem to work, it gave me a compiling error. Ill try to work my way around it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What's the compile error? It should say something else. Otherwise try going Debug -> Compile VBAProject in the VBA menu bar at the top.

Comment: It worked, must have been an error on my part. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

You could build the message up like this.

```
Sub GetValue()
Dim strName As String
Dim strMessage As String

    strName = InputBox("Please enter your name", "Enter name")
    
    strMessage = Join(Array("Hello, " & strName, _
                    "Use the grade calculator to find the total marks you need to score in the final exam in order to meet your expectations, given every mark other than the final exam mark", _
                    "Best of luck", _
                    "Please enter all your current marks and the overall mark that you desire (/100)- Start entering from cell G9"), vbCrLf)

    
    MsgBox strMessage, , "Welcome " & strName
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey there, ill check this code out and see if it works. Thanks!